# why childprocess can't catch 'SIGINT'

Tags: node.js

```
father.js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('node',['child.js']); 

setInterval(function(){
  child.kill('SIGINT');
},2000);

child.on('exit',function(code,signal){
 console.log('process exit '+code+' '+signal);
});

child.js
process.stdin.resume();
process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  console.log('Got SIGINT. Press Control-D to exit.');
});
```

node version : 0.10.17

why childprocess can't catch 'SIGINT'?
but if you run node child.js alone, it can cathch signal for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> terminate cmd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does get the `SIGINT`! Just that you are not listening to the child process output. Add this line in father.js to see it.

```
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: Yes,you are right.I miss that line.But it still can't work.can you try

Comment: I was able to run the program, it showed Got SIGINT. after every 2 seconds.

Comment: maybe the node's version , can you tell your node version and running platform?